# Computing the Euler-Lagrange PDE for a given action

Tags: field-theory

I am a bit confused on how to compute the Euler Lagrange equation for the action
\begin{align}
S(\phi, \bar\phi) = \int d^2xdt\ \left\{|\nabla \phi(t, x)|^2-|\partial_t \phi(t, x)|^2+\phi_1(t, x)^2\phi_2(t, -x)\right\}
\end{align}
where $\phi = \phi_1+i\phi_2$, i.e. $\phi_i$ are real-valued functions. The Euler-Lagrange equations should be a coupled system of PDEs. In fact, for the quadratic part, I get the d'Alembertian box operator. But for the cubic part, I am a bit confused by the $\phi_2(-x)$ part. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Kai Chung. Welcome to Phys.SE. 1. What's with all the minor edits and rollbacks? 2. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may proceed as follows, when making a variation over $\phi_2 (t, x)$, replace $x \rightarrow -x$, so that $\phi_1(t, x) \rightarrow \phi_1 (t, -x)$. Then variating over $\phi_2$, one obtains:
$$
\frac{\delta S}{\delta \phi_2(t, x)} = \Box\phi_2 +  \phi_1^2 (t, -x)
$$
For the $\phi_1$ :
$$
\frac{\delta S}{\delta \phi_1(t, x)} = \Box\phi_1 +  2 \phi_1 (t, x) \phi_2(t, -x)
$$

Comment: Once you mentioned it, this now seems obvious. Many thanks.  P.S. I think you forgot the negative sign when you did the change of variables.

Comment: @KaiChung, is the variable $x$ 3-dimensional? I thought, that you're dealing with (2+1) dimensional case (t, x_1, x_2)

Comment: Ah. You are right.